# como ejecutar una función al cargar una pagina en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Un cordial saludo, tengo un inconveniente con un componente, el cual esta dividido en 
app.component y su respectivo .html, necesito que una funcion se ejecute al cargar la pagina, al cargarse
el modal que tengo en este componente, he intentado con $(document).ready(), pero no ha funcionado,
creo que es un problema en la forma en que hago el llamado, no entiendo muy bien como funciona todavía,

Cuando realizo el llamado al en un ng-touchstart, me funciona perfecto:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <a class="boton grande intermedio"  ng-touchstart="$ctrl.listConve()">Validar</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

pero necesito cargarlo en este select:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
    <select class="form-control" id="convenio" name="selectConvenio" placeholder="Convenio" >
      <option selected>Elegir Convenio...</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in $ctr.dataList">{{$option.nombreConvenio}}</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

intente llamarlo de esta forma:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(
    function(){
        alert('funciona');
        $ctrl.listConve()
    })
 </script>
```

pero tampoco funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has intentado con * ng-init="function" *.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Por ejemplo, utilizándolo de esta manera.

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-init="inicioAlgo()">
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.llave}}">
                {{option.atributoAMostrar}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```